# python/shell script to connect to Karaf console

Tags: python, shell, grep, karaf

I am writing a script in python which can connect to karaf console like sudo ./client and after logging I want to see what and all bundles are active by using commands like list| grep -i active.I want 1 single script for that.

So these two commands I want to use in my script.

Comment: Can you provide two things for us: first, show us the exact commands you'd run from a command line that you want to run in Python; second, some example output from those commands.

Comment: @erapert the command i want to run is list | grep -i active. but before that i eed to connect to my karaf console

Comment: Then the answer I gave should work. If so then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So you need:

1. run a command and get its output
2. parse the output and look for things

Check out the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) for how to do this.

It should be something like this (I'm not at all familiar with Karaf...):

```
# output=`list | grep -i active`

p1 = Popen(["list"], stdout=PIPE)
# notice "stdin=p1.stdout"
p2 = Popen(["grep", "-i active"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
# Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
p1.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```